# Only allow execution of a binary after second authentication via own user id

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have this requirement which is hard to achieve.

1) user login via his AD login to a windows 10 workstation.
2) he does not have access to run a particular binary which is to perform file transfer to a unix server via key pair authentication
3) he is allowed only to execute that binary after providing his own AD credentials via powershell PSCredentials

Is this achiveable or is there other similar workaround? The idea is to have a second authentication not to a shared account but rather the users own credentials.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it necessary to restrict the _binary_, instead of restricting access to the Unix server?

Comment: Are the credentials in step 1 the same used in step 3? Your last paragraph suggests they are not.

Comment: Cause by right this group of AD users do not have logins to the unix server and we also do not want to maintain their accounts on that server.  We would like to have them able to upload files only.

Comment: The credentials used in step 1 and 3 should be the same.  Shared account means a privileged ID.  Was trying to mimic a sudo or rbac in solaris where user enter their own password instead of target user password.